# Php that redirects to diff URL depending on the param value of the current html page

Tags: php

I really can't find a php regarding what I need. I made an initial php that points to "www.mydomain.com/test/index.html?v=1". Now what I want if when I click a link inside that page, it checks the v value and depending on the value, it redirects it to a specific url.  I have 3 v values with specific URLs, also if you can add a code if v is null. thanks a lot.

Comment: Please elaborate clearly what you want and how

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to make is a click.php that is in the webpage and I want the php to check the parameter of the webpage (eg. index.html?v=1), redirects the user depending on the value of V.

Answer (score 0):

Use header and switch case

May be your header not working , this occurs if you have **print** something before  redirect.

```
$v = $_GET['v'];

switch($v){
 case "1":
  header('location: YOUR LINK');
 break;
 case "2":
    header('location: YOUR LINK');
 break;
 case "3":
     header('location: YOUR LINK');
 break;
 default:
     header('location:DEFAULT');

}
```

O Using if -elseif -else

```
$v = $_GET['v'];

 if($v == 1){
     header('location: YOUR LINK');
     die;
 }
 elseif($v == 2){
    header('location: YOUR LINK');
    die;
 }
 elseif($v==3){
     header('location: YOUR LINK');
     die;
 }    
 else{
     header('location:DEFAULT LINK');
     die;
}
```

Comment: your code works if I make a click.php?v=1 (v=2,v=3). My webpage URL shows www.domain.com/test/index.html?V=1 and I am making a link inside that page that first check the v value of that html URL before it redirects user to somewhere else. my link is click.php Hope it somehow clarify.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 header('location: URL or Link');
```

with if conditions

```
    if($v==somthing){
        header('location: URL or Link');
    }elseif($v==$somthing_else){
        header('location: URL or Link');
    }else{
    }
```

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to make is a click.php that is in the webpage and I want the php to check the parameter of the webpage (eg. index.html?v=1), redirects the user depending on the value of V.